# Convert Gregorian date to Lunar date

Tags: r, gregorian-calendar

Is there a package or a function which converts a **Gregorian date** to a date using the **Lunar calendar**? I googled for quite a bit but could not find anything for `R`. Thanks!

Comment: [How to convert date to lunar date in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123679/how-to-convert-date-to-lunar-date-in-r) might help.

Comment: Thanks! I have seen that post and it can definitely be helpful. But I was wondering whether there is a function which takes Gregorian dates and converts them into the respective Lunar date (like `lunar_date('2018-05-04")` and then returns the respective date of the Lunar calendar). Anyone an idea whether a function like that exists?